# My antlr 4 left recursive expression not preserving the expression precedence order

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, recursion, antlr4

I defined the following simple left recursive expression grammar for antlr4:

```
grammar BugExample;

// Rule Definitions

value: expression EOF ;

real:
    '-'? CONSTANT    #constantReal |
    FLOAT            #variableReal
;

variable: IDENTIFIER ;

expression:  // Precedence (highest to lowest)
    real             #realExpression      |
    variable         #variableExpression  |
//  expression '!'   #factorialExpression |
    '-' expression   #inversionExpression
;


// Token Definitions

FRACTION: '.' ('0'..'9')* '1'..'9' ;

CONSTANT: 'e' | 'pi' ;

FLOAT: INTEGER FRACTION? ('e' INTEGER)? ;

IDENTIFIER: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')* ;

SPACE: (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

fragment
NATURAL: '1'..'9' ('0'..'9')* ;

fragment
INTEGER: '0' | '-'? NATURAL ;
```

Notice the commented out factorial expression in the expression types. Also notice that the definition of a FLOAT token allows for negative values so a negative real expression should take precedence over an inversion expression.  With the factorial expression commented out, the generated JS parser does indeed parse a negative constant '-e' correctly as a real expression.  However, if we uncomment the factorial expression and regenerate the parser, the '-e' is suddenly parsed as an inversion expression.  Here is the test code showing it:

```
'use strict';

var language = require('../BugExample');
var testCase = require('nodeunit').testCase;

module.exports = testCase({
    'Test Parser': function(test) {
        var testValues = ['5.27e-15', '-5.3e22','e', '-e', 'expo', '-expo'];
        var expectedResults = [
            'RealExpressionContext',      // positive real number
            'RealExpressionContext',      // negative real number
            'RealExpressionContext',      // positive real constant
            'RealExpressionContext',      // positive real constant
            'VariableExpressionContext',  // variable value
            'InversionExpressionContext'  // negative variable value
        ];
        test.expect(testValues.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < testValues.length; i++) {
            var value = testValues[i];
            console.log('\nTesting: ' + value);
            var expression = language.parseValue(value).getChild(0);
            test.strictEqual(expression.constructor.name, expectedResults[i]);
        }
        test.done();
    }
});
```

It turns out that adding *any* left recursive sub-rule type listed in the "Definitive Antlr 4 Reference" that begins with the expression e.g. "binary", "ternary", and "unary suffix" expressions, will cause this problem. I have only verified this for the generated JS parser.  When I look at the generated parser code it appears that the order of the case blocks in the expression() function get randomized when the problem occurs whereas they are in precedence order when the factorial expression is commented out.  Not sure if this is the cause or not, the code is too complex for me to understand ;-)

I placed the JavaScript project showing this example out at GitHub:
https://github.com/derknorton/antlr4-bug-example

To test it out do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/derknorton/antlr4-bug-example
cd antlr4-bug-example
npm install
grunt generate build
# it should work correctly
# then edit test/TestBugExample.js  to remove commented factorial expression
grunt generate build
# it should now show the problem
```

Hopefully I have provided enough detail for the antlr4 experts to determine the problem.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `-e` a negative constant or an inverted positive constant expression? To avoid the philosophical question (and ANTLR's operative difficulty with it), redefine your `CONSTANT` rule to `'-'? ( 'e' | 'pi')`. This should preclude the parser from having to deal with the problem.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but I had tried that before and the test gives the following parsing error for input like '-expo': "line 1:2 extraneous input 'xpo' expecting <EOF>".  The lexer is interpreting the '-e' as the CONSTANT and chopping it off early.

Comment: With regard to the importance between interpreting '-e' as a negative constant real value vs an inverted real expression, they have different semantic meanings: the first is declarative and does not imply that an expression be evaluated by my VM at runtime.  This is important for my purposes since my VM is a secure VM that only runs in the cloud.  But my parser and associated parse tree visitors need to be able to run in a user's browser.  Therefore the parse tree visitors throw an exception when expressions are encountered during the parse tree conversions to JavaScript objects.

Comment: Add a `MINUS: '-' ;` rule at the end of the lexer and modify the inversion alt and `INTEGER` fragment to use `MINUS`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that approach as well and it still gives the "Error: 'InversionExpressionContext' === 'RealExpressionContext'" unit test error when I uncomment the factorial expression subrule.  The problem is that in both cases the lexer is returning the right token (and defining only one token for '-') but the parser is getting the precedence wrong and invoking the wrong expression subrule.

Comment: UPDATE: I tested the same grammar using the generated Java parser and it works fine, so this is a bug in the code generator for the JavaScript parser.  In the generated Java parser the order of the 'case' blocks in the ExpressionContext:expression() method are the same as the order of the sub-rules in the expression rule, thus preserving the precedence order.  In the generated JavaScript parser the order of the case blocks appears to be random (hash order perhaps?) and thus the precedence is not maintained. The github example: https://github.com/derknorton/antlr4-bug-example has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem turned out to be with a earlier versions of the antlr 4 parser generator.  My Grunt.js file was using the `grunt-antlr4` task which hasn't been updated to use the latest version of antlr4.  It was using version 4.5.1.  The problem seems to have been fixed after that version.  Full details of this realization are documented here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2201